# How can I install a VSIX package automatically, with WIX?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.5, vsix

I've got a WIX installation project for my application. As part of my solution I have a VSIX extension, that I want to install on the customer's Visual Studio.

What I don't know, is how to get WIX to automatically initiate the VSIX importer.

I tried following the advice on MSDN ([How to: Prepare Extensions for Windows Installer Deployment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/b6b06bff-5464-4bff-8ffb-66bbae6debe0/) as well as [Installing a VSIX as part of a Larger installation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332502.aspx)), to no avail. Neither included guidance for WIX projects.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done through a custom action which launches VSIXInstaller.exe with the appropriate command line. There is a discussion about this here: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/VSIX-after-installation-td4975318.html

Perhaps this will also help: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/pga/deploying-a-vsix-from-a-msi/

Comment: Thanks! The last link **REALLY** helped!

Answer (score 5):

WiX v3.6 supports the VsixPackage element to directly manage VSIX packages.

Comment: Is that functionality stable in 3.6? How about WiX 3.6 in general?

Comment: Be aware that using VsixPackage and perMachine installations only installs the extension for admin (switch /admin in VSIXInstaller.exe). It will not be visible when opening Visual Studio without administrative privileges (ie: when not run as administrator)