# How to execute VSTO post-install by WiX

Tags: wix, installation, vsto, wix3.5

I need to run some VSTOs after they been installed. Everything I tried came out negative.

One example:
    `<Property Id="runcmd">start</Property>`

```
<CustomAction Id="RunOutlookVSTO"
              Property="runcmd"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="asyncNoWait"
              ExeCommand="[SourceDir]Outlook2010AddIn.vsto">
</CustomAction>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RunOutlookVSTO"
          After="PublishProduct">NOT INSTALLED</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Error: No reaction.

Second example: replace start with cmd
Error: No reaction.

Third example: Replace start with msiexec and msiexec /i
Error: msiexec help screen and "did not find any msi to exec"

Fourth example: `<Custom action id="RunOutlookVSTO" etc>`
Error: Does not understand custom at compile.

EDIT:
Seems to be a bit of a confusion, just to be clear - yes I tried the registry key, and it is being ignored by the Office applications (Outlook, Word, Excel).

```
<RegistryKey Action="none" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\User Settings\">
            <RegistryKey Id="CreateVSTOOutlook" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" 
                         Key="OUR.Outlook2010AddIn\Create\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\OUR.Outlook2010AddIn">
              <RegistryValue Id="CmdLineOutlook" Name="CommandLineSafe" Value="1" Type="integer"></RegistryValue>
              <RegistryValue Id="descOutlook" Name="Description" Value="Tilføjelsesprogram til Outlook 2010" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
              <RegistryValue Id="nameOutlook" Name="FriendlyName" Value="Outlook 2010 AddIn" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
              <RegistryValue Id="LoadOutlook" Name="LoadBehavior" Value="3" Type="integer"></RegistryValue>
              <RegistryValue Id="manifestOutlook" Name="Manifest" Value="[INSTALLDIR]OUR.Outlook2010AddIn.vsto|vstolocal" Type="string"></RegistryValue>
            </RegistryKey>
          </RegistryKey>
```

Any ideas what I could try next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install a VSIX package automatically, with WIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423507/how-can-i-install-a-vsix-package-automatically-with-wix)

Comment: Besides, WiX 3.6 has this functionality out of the box (see VsixPackage element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vsto addins are not standalone programs you can execute. They are dll's that get loaded and then called by the respective office programs through a special bootstrapper.

In your case starting OUTLOOK should load the addin (if it's registered properly). And nothing else will.

-- EDIT --

The .vsto file extension gets associated with the VstoInstaller.exe which is the program you try to run. Note that the vsto file is not a program and as such can't be executed/run. It is a configuration file that is understood by the vstoinstaller (program).

For a default installation VSTOInstaller.exe can be found in

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe

it has a /help switch but the install syntax is:

> VSTOInstaller.exe /i \servername\foldername\AddIn.vsto

for more info see [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772078.aspx)

Comment: Sorry no, after I installed/copy pasted the dlls and whatnot to the folder, I have sofar manually executed the vsto's. In the old days, yes I had a registry key that was recognised by Outlook and the other office aps and hence integrated into it. Now, not so much, they ignore that same registry entry.

Comment: It's not clear to me: How you 'manually execute' a 'vsto'? They are dll's not exe's. And can you be more specific about what you need to accomplish by executing them from the wix. Does it have to do with the problem that your installation doesn't seem to properly register the vsto solution and that it doesn't show up in outlook?

Comment: I double click or select and press enter on the VSTOs. After I copied the files to the folder in question, I expect to have the functionality of the addin present in Outlook (and the others). That doesn't happen till I've executed the VSTOs.

Comment: Ahh, I just saw your edit. Getting close now, prelim tests show I need to be doing some hax to make it work. Thank you, I appreciate it.