# Embeddeding the vsix file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

Recently, I download **`codesnippets`** file. It's extension name is `.vsix` file so how I used or install file via `Visual Studio 2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio installation will register a handler for the VSIX extension.  This allows you to just double click on the file and it will run the installer.

In case that association is broken you can manually run the installer.  It is located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe

Comment: @NazimAli if that doesn't exist then it would seem your Visual Studio installation is incomplete or corrupt.  It's a part of the standard installation package

Comment: I finded and when I lunching it's given an error
This extension is not installable on any currently installed products

Comment: @NazimAli that suggests that the VSIX isn't targeted for VS 2012. Its likely targeted for VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you just need to double click a .vsix file to install the plugin.
I think codesnippets.vsix has been made specifically for VS 2013, so I am not sure it will work with VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

first you should search for this problem on your behalf it is discussed many times.

have a look at:
[Stack Overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423507/how-can-i-install-a-vsix-package-automatically-with-wix)
and 
[MS Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on that file,it will install automatically.